# How to disable JUnit 5 test in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit5

I have JUnit 5 unit and integration tests that I want to run in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3.  When I right clicked on a folder and chose `Run As -> JUnit Test`, I expected to see all tests under that folder run, except for those with the `@Disabled` annotation.  However, that annotation seems to be ignored, so unwanted tests got run:

[image: "Disabled" test that got run anyway]

How can I make Eclipse/JUnit skip the test?

Comment: Can you try to diasble the entire test class using @Disabled ? If this also does not work perhaps there is a bug with the annotation....

Comment: Does upgrading to Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) which was released yesterday fix this issue?

Comment: From which package are you importing the `@Test` annotation?

Comment: @Marc Philipp - org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Comment: @Rann Lifshitz - I can disable the entire test class using Disabled

Comment: Can you please post the code for `MessageTranslationIT` including imports?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Maven project, you have to use a newer version of the Surefire plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Maybe this doesn’t help with running tests of a folder, but it should work when building/testing the complete project.